# SQL/PHP "WHERE" not returning correct value?

Tags: php, sql, where-clause

The code will display the returned values and and if it is greater than one it will return "Yes".  But I am having trouble with the WHERE clause in $check.  When I take it out the code works just fine but when I add it, the page returns incorrect values.  Any ideas what's wrong?

```
<?php

$con = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1","root","","lian");

$u= $_GET['username'];
$pw = $_GET['password'];

$check = "SELECT username,password FROM users WHERE username='$u' AND password='$pw'";

$login = mysqli_query($con,$check) or die(mysqli_error($con));

$num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($login);
echo "$num_rows \n";

if (mysqli_num_rows($login) == 1) {
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($login);
echo 'Yes'; 
exit;
}

else {
echo 'No';
exit;
}
```

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injections. You need to escape any and all user input.

Comment: What do you see when you echo out the variables contained in $_GET?

Comment: And password in plaintext on the database?!? Hash it with a salt

Comment: I hope this is only a PHP learning experiment, because it would be exploited in few instants if deployed.

Answer (score 0):

Leaving aside the injection vulnerabilities, it may be because of special characters or whitespace. Try trim'ing your GET values.

```
$u = trim($_GET['username']);
$pwd = trim($_GET['password']);
```

Are you getting the number of results as 0? Also try echoing the statement in a development environment to check exactly what the statement is.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
$u= trim(mysqli_real_escape_string($_GET['username']));
$pw = trim(mysqli_real_escape_string($_GET['password']));
$check = "SELECT username,password FROM users WHERE username='$u' AND password='$pw'";
```

Also I hope you are ensuring unique combination of username and password.
Because suppose there are **two** entries in your users table

> username="abc" password ="12345"

Then mysqli_num_rows() function will return two rows and the

```
if (mysqli_num_rows($login) == 1)
```

condition will return **false** meaning the user desn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

The above comments are valid to improve the security of your code and protect vs sql injection.

Regarding your actual problem if the code executes correctly when you don't have the where clause in place but fails when you do there are a couple of possibilities:

1. The username or password are wrong - where wrong can mean they have extra whitespace, case insensitivities or that the column names are incorrect(case sensitive database?)
2. The string you are passing to the server is not displaying correctly.

Check both options by doing an echo of $u, $pw and $check right after you form your SQL string.  If it's still not clear then copy whatever is echoed for $check and past it directly into the parser(management studio I guess?) and see what it returns.

Good Luck.

Comment: I echoed the $check and this is the return value SELECT username,password FROM users WHERE username='' AND password=''